# Google Maps fractional zoom only works 3 times

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps JavaScript API v3, it is possible to change the zoom of a map using the `setZoom` method, see the [Map class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map).

I am able to set the zoom to a fractional value and it works, i.e. `gmap.setZoom(1.1)` works. However, it stops working on the 4th call with a fractionnal zoom, i.e.:

- `gmap.setZoom(1.1)` works
- `gmap.setZoom(1.2)` works
- `gmap.setZoom(1.3)` works
- `gmap.setZoom(1.4)` doesn't work, the map turns grey.

It's not the `1.4` value that doesn't work. Setting `1` then `1.4` does work. It really seems to be on the 4th time that we set a fractionnal value.

Is this a known bug or is there a way to avoid the map to turn grey after  multiple zooming using fractionnal zooms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised it works ever. Fractional zoom levels are not supported.  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions):

> **zoom** | Type:  number
>
> The initial Map zoom level. Required. Valid values: ***Integers*** between zero, and up to the supported maximum zoom level.

Related issues in the issue tracker:

- [Issue 10977: Bug: Zoom cannot be set to e.g. 6.5 initially - map is shown in gray color only](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10977)
- [Issue 9948: Fractional zoom level(fine zoom)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9948)

Comment: That's for the zoom level to initialize the map with.  For the `setMap` method, the documentation is this: `setZoom(zoom:number)`, i.e. it's not specified that it only takes **Integers**.  A number can technically be `1.1` and it works.

Comment: It is being used by the same code (it determines the tiles loaded for the map)

Comment: I've also tested using fractions and it seems to work. I should add, that when I interact with the map (dragging, clicking on a pin, etc.) it will then zoom in to what sees to be the absolute value. Meaning if I have `zoom: 13.4` after interacting with the map it will zoom OUT, presumably to `zoom: 13`; if I set at `zoom: 12.8` it will then zoom IN after interacting.